# SQL How to; Try-Catch error info to error-log table, for stored proc executed within a transaction?

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, translation, try-catch

In my stored procs, I am using Try-Catch, and calling an error handling procedure in the Catch block that will log the error details in a ErrorLog table, then rethrow the error.

In my C# code, I am executing my stored procedures using:

```csharp
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
    // execute stored procs
    scope.Complete();
}
```

The problem I'm having, if the transaction is aborted (scope.Complete is never called), my error handling stored proc does rethrow the sql error, but can't log the error into the ErrorLog table because it is in the context of Transaction; Is there ANY way around this !? I already know that data cannot be inserted when a transaction is in an uncommittable state, so how do I exit the transaction and still log the error ?

TSQL code:

```
BEGIN PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpsertSomething]
    @SomethingID BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- do something
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC dbo.cp_RethrowError
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RethrowError]
    @ErrorLogID [INT] = 0 OUTPUT -- Contains the ErrorLogID of the row inserted
                                 -- by cp_RethrowError in the ErrorLog table.
AS
BEGIN
    -- Return if there is no error information to retrieve.
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() IS NULL
        RETURN;

    DECLARE 
        @ErrorMessage           VARCHAR(4000),
        @FormattedErrorMessage  VARCHAR(4000),
        @ErrorNumber            INT,
        @ErrorSeverity          INT,
        @ErrorState             INT,
        @ErrorLine              INT,
        @ErrorProcedure         VARCHAR(200);

    -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
    -- capture information for RAISERROR.
    SELECT 
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

    -- Build the message string that will contain original
    -- error information.
    SELECT @FormattedErrorMessage = 
        'ErrorLogID %d, Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, ' + 
            'Line %d, Message: '+ @ErrorMessage;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Data insertion/modification is not allowed when 
        -- a transaction is in an uncommittable state.
        IF XACT_STATE() = -1 BEGIN
            SET @ErrorLogID = 0;
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            INSERT [dbo].[ErrorLog] 
            (
                ErrorNumber, 
                ErrorSeverity, 
                ErrorState, 
                ErrorProcedure, 
                ErrorLine, 
                ErrorMessage
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (
                @ErrorNumber,
                @ErrorSeverity,
                @ErrorState,
                @ErrorProcedure,
                @ErrorLine,
                @ErrorMessage
            );

            -- Pass back the ErrorLogID of the row inserted
            SELECT @ErrorLogID = @@IDENTITY;
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'An error occurred in stored procedure cp_RethrowError.';
    END CATCH

    -- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
    -- the original error information.
    RAISERROR 
    (
        @FormattedErrorMessage, 
        @ErrorSeverity, 
        1,
        @ErrorLogID,     -- parameter: ErrorLogID in ErrorLog table.
        @ErrorNumber,    -- parameter: original error number.
        @ErrorSeverity,  -- parameter: original error severity.
        @ErrorState,     -- parameter: original error state.
        @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
        @ErrorLine       -- parameter: original error line number.
    );
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since transactions are an all or nothing deal, the only way to get done what I'm wanting done, is to call ROLLBACK TRANSACTION inside of the Catch block, before calling my error handling call.

My error log ends up with the error I want logged, but in my .Net catch block, I end up with a complaint from SQL: "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."

I can live with that!

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the error log entries first into a table variable (which should have the same structure as the real log table). Rollback does not clear table variables. At the end you only have to insert the content of the table variable into the real log table.

I did not try it, but it may work.
A feature like autonomous transaction is still missing from SQL Server (Oracle already has it). Whatever you do in an autonomous transaction is independent from the main transaction. That's exactly what you need in case of error logging: especially when the transaction is rolled back, you still want to know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sequencing problem. Check the transaction count in your error handler.
Steps:
  1. Get the original error information first into @variables or an @table.
  2. Check your transaction count and if it is greater than 0, roll it back. 
  3. Insert the error information that you have just collected in step 1.
Finished.